# How to mock a function within useEffect in Context Provider?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, use-effect, react-testing-library, react-context

I am following the setup in react-testing-library for wrapping the test component with providers as in here: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup

some portion related:

```
...
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
   <ContextProvider>
       <Router>{children}</Router>
   </ContextProvider>      
</ThemeProvider>
...
```

in the ContextProvider I have

```
useEffect(()=>{
    initPage();
},[])
```

How can I avoid this useEffect to not to run or mock initPage?
(I have seen examples like jest.mock(React, useEffect) bla bla but what i want is only to avoid this initPage call for any test I run in the app. I will override the value of Provider and run tests thats ok but for any test I want to make it as default to block ONLY this function ONLY in this provider.That's all. I think i should add jest.mock/fn or smth in test-utils.jsx but how?)

Comment: First of all, where does `initPage` come from? You can mock the module that exports `initPage` function.

Comment: it is inside the ContextProvider component block.

Comment: Did you try using jest.mock on the module that initPage is imported from? https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules